# How do I set a quota for file storage?

Tags: 8, multi-sites, acquia-cloud

We are running a multisite Drupal 8 installation in Acquia Cloud platform, which uses AWS.

The site structure looks like this:

```
/html [main D8 installation]
/html/sites/site1 [D8 multisite]
/html/sites/site2 [D8 multisite]
/html/sites/site3 [D8 multisite]
/html/sites/siteN [D8 multisite]
```

Is there a way to limit how much data a single site in Drupal 8 can store in its public files directory?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should reword your question. As is, your question is incidental to D8; it's more about server storage management on Acquia's platform. If you're looking a Drupal-centric solution, you ask something like "how do I set a quota for file storage in Drupal 8?"

Comment: Cheers, edited the question. So the correct way is to ask for a D8 solution here and then ask another Q in Unix's StackExchange site for a possible solution that way?

Comment: Yeah, I would try ServerFault since its more popular and the question is about server administration. You might want to clean up the question body too (shorter the better) so you'll better attract Drupallers who know about file storage quota solutions.

Comment: Made the Q more concise. Looked into ServerFault and I'm starting to think that the best solution will be to write a cron script that monitors each multisite every night and notifies the admins of those sites if they are reaching some set limit of data in their files/ folder.